# Allow is_staff=False to access specific page Django

Tags: django

I have a change password function which only allowed `is_staff`=`False` to access, not allowed `is_staff`=`True` to view this page.

Is there any way to do this?

I only found `staff_member_requird`, but this is for staff.

```
def change_password(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PasswordChangeForm(request.user, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            update_session_auth_hash(request, user) 
            messages.info(request, 'Your password has been changed successfully!')
    else:
        form = PasswordChangeForm(request.user)
    return render(request, 'registration/change_password.html', {'form': form,})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`user_passes_test`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test) decorator with any arbitrary function. So:

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: not u.is_staff)
def change_password(request):
   ...
```